# widgetvar composite component VS naming container

Tags: jsf, primefaces, composite-component

I've make a composite component with an overlayPanel inside. I put my widgetVar like [BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc) suggest: `widgetVar="#{cc.id}_MyOverlayPanelWidget"` and refer to with `PF('#{cc.id}_MyOverlayPanelWidget').hide()`.

My need is to use my composite component into an `p:tabview`. It's valid to have same id for my component inside different naming container. The issue is when I load my 2 tabs, I have same widgetVar for 2 object. I won't use `cc:clientId` cause `:` isn't valid for widgetVar. What do you recommend for this situation?

Comment: Note that in current versions of PF, the widgetVar is not directly a javascript variable anymore, but instead a lookup in a javascript map. The widgetVar is now just a key, and can have any formatting you want, including ':'.

Answer (score 0):

Use `cc.clientId` and replace all colons with a valid symbol. That's what PrimeFaces itself does when autogenerating widgetVars, it replaces colons with underscores.